# What is the migration path from JsonApiDotNetCore to .NET Core 3.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-3.1

I am attempting to migrate a Web API from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1.

JsonApiDotNetCore is built around Dependency Injection (DI) whereas .NET Core 3.x seems to be moving to eliminate DI, with 3 exceptions. Is JsonApiDotNetCore effectively going away? If yes, does anyone know the correct migration path? I checked the GitHub site and do not see anything on their end.

https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore/blob/master/README.md

https://andrewlock.net/avoiding-startup-service-injection-in-asp-net-core-3/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Where did you get the idea that ".NET Core 3.x seems to be moving to eliminate DI"? It's simply not true. Andrew Lock article is describing just the fact you can't inject services in Startup class constructor, thus some other way is required to use already registered service in Startup class. DI in .NET Core 3.x is still a thing (and it will be in next versions too). JsonApiDotNetCore 4.x is compatible with .NET Core 3.x (read at the bottom of https://github.com/json-api-dotnet/JsonApiDotNetCore)

Comment: @ClaudioValerio Got it - that makes sense. I see what happened too. The actual JsonApiDotNetCore assembly needs to be manually updated from 3.1 to 4.x through the NuGet package manager console because 4.0.0 alpha* is not available in the NuGet UI dropdown. So, I was getting erroneous Async errors (the name was dropped from methods). By manually replacing the package, the errors went away. If you want to post the answer then I will check it. Thank you.